# My laptop fans get loud when I watch GIFs and low quality videos

Tags: laptop, fan

My laptop fans get loud when I watch GIFs and low quality videos, why is this happening? Whenever I scroll through Discord and there is a GIF, my laptop fans decided to go super loud. And whenever I load a video that's slightly low quality, my laptop fans go loud. Why is this happening?

Comment: Fans speed up to increase airflow. Airflow is needed to cool down the chips (GPU/CPU mostly). Vents may need cleaning; thermal paste may need to be reapplied.

Comment: Most likely because those forms of video compression do not support hardware acceleration, and require more CPU work, which heats up the CPU. the fans are trying to cool it off. try using a tool like speedfan or coretemp or whatever to monitor your CPU temp. if it gets above 80C, I'd certainly expect your fans to spin up to pretty high speed.

Comment: Cool, I'm happy it's a normal thing! That lifts quite a lot of weight off of my chest!